# C++20 concepts: int not swappable_with int

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

I'm trying out C++20's concepts, and either `std::swappable_with` is undefined (Visual Studio, using `/std:c++latest`) or its constraints are not matched by the MCVE below (g++10 using `-std=c++2a`) -- that is, `int` is not swappable with `int` (!). What's the fix for this? If `int` can't be swapped with `int`, I don't see *anything* working.

```
#include <concepts> 

template <typename T, typename U>
requires std::swappable_with<T,U>
void mySwap(T& t, U& u)
{
    T temp = t; t = u; u = temp;
}

int main()
{
    int x, y;
    mySwap(x, y);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `std::is_swappable_with_v<int, int>` gives me 0 with libstdc++: https://godbolt.org/z/n4U-W6

Comment: I don't have C++20 but you could just check: std::is_copy_assignable<T>::value for both types then swap. If nothing works for you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`std::swappable_with<T, U>` checks whether `swap` can be invoked (after `using std::swap;`) with arguments `std::declval<T>()` and `std::declval<U>()`. With `T` and `U` being `int`, both arguments are *rvalues*, which cannot be bound to `std::swap` parameters, since these are (non-const) lvalue references.

---

You wonder that `int` cannot be swapped with `int` — that's right, you cannot write `std::swap(1, -1);`.

Comment: That's absolutely crazy. What general user of these features should have to think in this level of detail and esoteric theory? If you have two `int` objects, they are definitely swappable (it's the canonical example of `std::swap`!) so for `std::swappable_with<int, int>` to fail is mind-boggling. Who comes up with these features ‍♂️

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings _If you have two int objects, they are definitely swappable._ — That's not true. This holds only if both those objects are lvalues. If both are rvalues, or one is rvalue and second one lvalue, they are not swappable (with `std::swap`).

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings: "*What general user of these features should have to think in this level of detail and esoteric theory?*" And what happens when that "level of detail and esoteric theory" becomes relevant? Being able to distinguish between operations on lvalues and rvalues is important. In this case in particular, what would happen if the user took `T` and `U` by value instead of by reference? The function would compile, but it wouldn't do something useful. So on some level, the user already has to know some "esoteric theory".

Comment: @DanielLangr `s/objects/variables/`

Comment: @DanielLangr BTW objects cannot be lvalues or rvalues. Only expressions have value categories.

Comment: @NicolBolas A sensible language should be expressive and easy to use for the common/obvious cases first, with complexity an optional extra. C++ has loooong ago forgotten this.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings: "*`s/objects/variables/`*" Concepts don't take variables; they take *types*. The sooner a user understands that difference, the better.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings But expressions can represent objects themselves, such as variable names or literals.

Comment: @DanielLangr Yes, indeed, they can

Comment: To be fair, I will say one thing that mitigates this is that `is_swappable<T>` (which delegates to `is_swappable_with<T&, T&>`!) seems to provide the "expressive and easy to use for the common/obvious cases" angle

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings If you want to complain about how C++ works, this is not the right place. I didn't invent the `std::swappable_with` metafunction. And, I believe, anyone can become a member of the C++ committee or submit proposals for language updates :).

Comment: @DanielLangr I'm not blaming you. It was a throwaway comment like we make every day. Sorry to have offended

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings I am not, just wanted to point out that our discussion is off-topic.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215592/discussion-between-daniel-langr-and-asteroids-with-wings).

Answer (score 9):

Use `std::swappable_with<T&,U&>` - swappable with cares about value category, encoded by reference, as well as type.

You are in effect asking if rvalues of type `int` can be swapped.  And it says "no"; you cannot swap to rvalue `int`s.

This might be confusing, but if you do this:

```
template <class T, class U>
requires std::swappable_with<T,U>
void mySwap(T&& t, U&& u) {
  auto temp = std::forward<T>(t);
  t = std::forward<U>(u);
  u = std::move(temp);
}
```

it becomes a bit more natural.  Here, we use forwarding references, and the l/rvalue categories of the argument are stored along side the bare types in `T` and `U` respectively.

Note that the above could permit rvalues to be swapped, if objects of that type are `swappable_with` each other.